# Role Specific Dashboards

Tags: dashboard

Can somebody tell me if i can make dashboards role specific in salesforce?
basically i want to show dashboards on home page layout according to user who logs in!! If he is a caller for ex. then he should see one dashboard, if he is manager he should see another dashboard on his home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can do that.

1. Create 2 profiles, one for caller and one for Manager and configure Home Page layouts with respective dashboards and assign to the profiles.
2. You can create single Home page layout and instruct users to select dashboard from Customize Page Link as below.

[image: dashboard change]

And clicking on that link you can customize the page.

[image: customize page]